# MapBox cache not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I'm trying to cache maps in MapBox. When app in online, everything works. The tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache is being called properly.

Then, I relaunch the app offline. Instead of map, the RMMapView shows white color only.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[RMConfiguration sharedInstance] setAccessToken:@"pk......"];

    RMTileCache  * tileCache = [[RMTileCache alloc] initWithExpiryPeriod:0];
    [tileCache setBackgroundCacheDelegate:self];

    tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"mirap.ld8dbe2c"];    
    mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:viewMapView.bounds
                                     andTilesource:tileSource];

    [mapView.tileSource setCacheable:YES];
    [viewMapView addSubview:mapView];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    RMSphericalTrapezium rect = [mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox];
    mapView.tileCache.backgroundCacheDelegate = self;
    [mapView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:mapView.tileSource
                                               southWest:rect.southWest
                                               northEast:rect.northEast
                                                 minZoom:10.0
                                                 maxZoom:20.0];

}
- (void)tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache {

    NSLog(@"DONE!");

}
```

Comment: Btw in same project I'm using Realm.io. May that cause a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need:

[`mapbox-ios-sdk-offline/ViewController.swift#L38-L44`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-offline/blob/9b4da16cf449631a756c55321a6e402d9bac10da/Mapbox%20Offline/ViewController.swift#L38-L44)

In short, initializing a tile source with a map ID is shorthand for requesting a remote metadata URL.

[`-[RMMapboxSource initWithMapID:]`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/Classes/RMMapboxSource.html#//api/name/initWithMapID:)

> This method requires a network connection in order to download the TileJSON used to define the tile source.

Instead you want to also cache the `tileSource.tileJSON` and use it to initialize the tile source when offline.

[`-[RMMapboxSource tileJSON]`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/Classes/RMMapboxSource.html#//api/name/tileJSON)

> Useful for saving locally to use in instantiating a tile source while offline.

Comment: this is not working for me. after caching the tileJson string, i try to open a map as such: mapSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithTileJSON:map_Tiles]; and pre-fetch as such:  [self.mapboxView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:self.mapboxView.tileSource
                                                       southWest:sw
                                                       northEast:ne
                                                         minZoom:minZoom
                                                         maxZoom:maxZoom];